# How to use Dropdown with ng-model in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying angularjs ng-model for use of dropdown for my Selenium `WebDriver` code but it is not working.
My code is.

```
package automation.test;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","../geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);     
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    String baseUrl = "http://abc/bluestar/Admin";

    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);       
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Rough Transaction"))).click();      
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/bluestar/Admin/RoughTransaction/RoughInward']")).click();
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-model='RoughInward.TransationModeId']")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("LOCAL PURCHASE ");
    /*WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-model='TransationModeId']"));
    Select select = new Select(webElement);
    select.selectByVisibleText("LOCAL PURCHASE");*/
   // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("LogOut"))).click();
    driver.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
}
}
```

It is showing below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@ng-model='RoughInward.TransationModeId'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

HTML is

```html
<select class="form-control MinWith input-sm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="RoughInward.TransationModeId" required="" autofocus="" ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in TransactionModeS" style="width: 100%;">
  <option selected="selected" class="" value="">Select Transaction Mode</option>
  <option label="IMPORT" value="number:12">IMPORT</option>
  <option label="LOCAL PURCHASE" value="number:13">LOCAL PURCHASE</option>
  <option label="CONSIGNMENT PURCHASE" value="number:15">CONSIGNMENT PURCHASE</option><option label="MEMO PURCHASE" value="number:18">MEMO PURCHASE</option>
</select>
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Please add the html

Comment: @Guy html done please check

Comment: I don't know why you want to locate your element by ng-model? Use classes or at least id's to adress your elements and get them by webdriver

Comment: @CodeNashor id is not there and Class is used multiple time so tell me how can i use it in code?

Comment: Maybe with some parent selectors? ng-model selector is the worst thing you can do...but if you really want that, implement a sleeper. But it's also possible, that 'RoughInward.TransationModeId' will be replaced by the value. My advice: Try to add an ID to your element, otherwise use more selectors to identify your element wihout ng-model selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add implicit wait after the `driver` initialization

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will try to locate elements for up to 10 seconds.

You can also try to locate by partial `ng-model`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[ng-model*='TransationModeId']"));
```

Comment: @NiteshTailor `NoSuchElementException` or `Element is not visible`?

Comment: after adding above code, it is  showing Element is not visible.

Comment: @NiteshTailor You can use again `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(...))`

Comment: In python it's `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[ng-model*='TransationModeId']");`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void waitForElement(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) 
{        
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
    wait.pollingEvery(250,  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.withTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class); //make sure that this exception is ignored
    Function<WebDriver, WebElement> function = new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
            {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver arg0) {
                    System.out.println("Checking for the element!!");                       
                    if(element != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Target element found");
                    }
                    return element;
                }
            };

    wait.until(function);
}
```

Use this fulent wait funtion that will wait as much as is needed. I don't advice using of implicit or explicit wait with Angular JS. 
You can call it before the select command:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-model='RoughInward.TransationModeId']"));
WaitHelper.waitForElement(el, driver);
```